Выдает ошибку при решении задачи на Golang
Условие задачи:

Дан неотсортированный слайс целых чисел. Напишите функцию UnderLimit(nums []int, limit int, n int) ([]int, error), которая будет возвращать первые n (либо меньше, если остальные не подходят) элементов, которые меньше limit. В случае ошибки функция должна вернуть nil и описание ошибки.

TEST`s
package main

import (
    "slices"
    "testing"
)

func TestUnderLimit(t *testing.T) {
    type test struct {
        nums      []int
        n         int
        limit     int
        expected  []int
        wantError bool
    }

    tests := []test{
        {
            nums:      []int{4, 7, 89, 3, 21, 2, 5, 7, 32, 4, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4, 6, 2, 115, 12},
            n:         5,
            limit:     3,
            expected:  []int{2, 0, 2},
            wantError: false,
        },
        {
            nums:      nil,
            wantError: true,
        },
        {
            nums:      []int{},
            n:         5,
            limit:     3,
            expected:  []int{},
            wantError: false,
        },
        {
            nums:      []int{3, 5, 6},
            n:         5,
            limit:     10,
            expected:  []int{3, 5, 6},
            wantError: false,
        },
        {
            nums:      []int{-13, 0, 6},
            n:         1,
            limit:     -5,
            expected:  []int{-13},
            wantError: false,
        },
        {
            nums:      []int{},
            n:         -1,
            limit:     5,
            wantError: true,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range tests {
        result, err := UnderLimit(tc.nums, tc.limit, tc.n)
        if tc.wantError {
            if err == nil {
                t.Fatalf("expec... File is too long to be displayed fully

Моё решение:
func UnderLimit(nums []int, limit int, n int) ([]int, error) {
    if n < 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("n cannot be negative")
    } else if n == 0 {
        result := make([]int, 0, 0)
        return result, nil
    }

    result := make([]int, 0, n)
    count := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        if num < limit {
            result = append(result, num)
            count++
        }
        if count == n {
            return result, nil
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}

Но выводится ошибка:
--- FAIL: TestUnderLimit (0.00s)
    source_test.go:62: expected an error
FAIL


Шестая попытка? Так и не сказали, что является "ошибкой"

Покажите функцию TestUnderLimit. Как мы сможем догадаться, в каких ситуациях тест ожидает ошибку?

Не очень понятно, что такое "в случае ошибки". Там прямо написано, что единственная возможная ошибка это n<0? А если n=0 это не ошибка? А если n> размера nums это не ошибка? Я не знаю. Может возможны ещё какие-то ошибки?

добавил функицию TestUnderLimit

ну я перепроверил ошибка может быть иной, но ни n=0, ни n> размера nums не является ошибкой

Добавьте весь код в виде текста и целиком. А не картинками. Из приведённого фрагмента непонятно, на каком тесте и почему ругается TestUnderLimit.

Судя по TestUnderLimit , ошибка ожидается в двух случаях: n<0 и если массив чисел представляет из себя nil. В остальных случаях ошибки быть не должно

Попробуйте такое решение:
func UnderLimit(nums []int, limit int, n int) ([]int, error) {
    if n < 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("n cannot be negative")
    }
    if nums == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("nums cannot be nil")
    }
    if n == 0{
        return []int{}, nil
    }

    result := make([]int, 0, n)
    count := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        if count == n {
            return result, nil
        }
        if num < limit {
            result = append(result, num)
            count++
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}


